# How to get id, based on ambiguous entries in table

Tags: sql, t-sql

Let's consider the following table.

```
Id(PK, int) | DocDate(long) | Sender(varchar) | Recipient(varchar) | PeriodStart(long) | PeriodEnd(long)
```

For every `Sender`, `Recipient`, `PerdiodStart`, `PeriodEnd` I'm writting multiple entries at different points in time. So the `DocDate` differs.

Now I've to select the id of the latest `DocDate`, foreach `Sender`, `Recipient`, `PeriodStart`, `PerdiodEnd`. The only solution I found by myself is using a CTE.

```
with prevFilter as (
    select   max(DocDate), Sender, Recipient, PeriodStart, PeriodEnd
    from     Table
    group
    by       Sender, Recipient, PeriodStart, PeriodEnd
)
select   Id
from     Table t
inner
join     prevFilter pf
         on  pf.DocDate = t.DocDate 
         and pf.Sender = t.Sender 
         and pf.Recipient = t.Recipient
         and pf.PeriodStart = t.PeriodStart
         and pf.PeriodEnd = t.PeriodEnd
```

You might now think, this query has a poor performance, but I could improve it with a clustered index.

But I'm wondering, if there isn't a faster and more elegant solution for this problem. Can anyone provide one?

Comment: Just to clarify, are you wanting the ID of the most recent record based on DocDate?

Comment: ...of the most recent record based on `DocDate` foreach `Sender`, `Recipient`, `PeriodStart`, `PerdiodEnd`...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lamak has the right idea but a few errors. This version should work.

```
with prevFilter as (
select   Id, 
         RN = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(
             PARTITION BY Sender, Recipient, PeriodStart, PeriodEnd
             ORDER BY DocDate DESC)
from     Table
)
select   Id
from     prevFilter t
where RN = 1
```

Comment: It's definitely faster. Thanks @all.

Answer (score 4):

You can use a CTE and `ROW_NUMBER`:

```
with prevFilter as (
    select   Id, 
             RN = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY Sender, Recipient, PerdiodStart, PeriodEnd
                                    ORDER BY DocDate DESC)
    from     Table
)
select   Id
from     prevFilter t
where RN = 1
```

Comment: Change 'Table' to 'prevFilter' in the outer select, but that should do it. Oh and get rid of the group by in the CTE.

Comment: Since JC came up first with the correct solution, he will get the mark. Hope you don't mind.

Comment: @DHN Of course I don't mind, it's the right thing to do in this case

Answer (score 1):

You could use SQL Server ranking functions to isolate the record with highest `DocDate` for each combination of `Sender,Recipient, PeriodStart, PeriodEnd` and then filter:

```
Select * from (
select  *, row_number() over (partition by Sender, 
                             Recipient, PeriodStart, PeriodEnd
      order by DocDate desc) as ranker
from     Table
) where ranker = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use:

```
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT DISTINCT Sender, Recipient, PeriodStart, PeriodEnd
    FROM YourTable t1
) t CROSS APPLY (
    SELECT TOP 1 Id
    FROM YourTable t2
    WHERE t2.Sender = t.Sender 
    AND t2.Recipient = t.Recipient
    AND t2.PeriodStart = t.PeriodStart
    AND t2.PeriodEnd = t.PeriodEnd
    ORDER BY DocDate DESC
) x
```

or:

```
SELECT *
FROM YourTable t1
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT *
    FROM YourTable t2
    WHERE t2.Sender = t1.Sender 
    AND t2.Recipient = t1.Recipient
    AND t2.PeriodStart = t1.PeriodStart
    AND t2.PeriodEnd = t1.PeriodEnd
    AND t2.DocDate>t1.DocDate
)
```

Razvan

Comment: This should have the same performance as my solution, shouldn't it?

Comment: Your solution should have better performance in most scenarios, but it depends on the available indexes. If you create an index on all of the columns in the WHERE clause, my queries might have a slightly lower cost.